# Ubuntu 16.04 - discover what services failed on startup

Tags: boot, systemd, logs

I upgraded my server from 14.04 LTS to 16.04 LTS this past weekend.

It did not go as smooth as hoped. And having to learn how to use `systemctl` and `journalctl` the hard way did not help.

Anyway: I noticed that some of the services fails to start on reboot, but text is passing by too fast for me to read **which** services fails.

... Is there a **quick** way to read it out of a log - or do I need to record boot process as a video and slow video down? :-)

I have learned that `journalctl -b0` refer to last boot, but can it be distilled any more?

Comment: Running `dmesg | grep FAILED` may be a good start point.

Comment: Unfortunately that did not help.

Comment: Output was empty.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After a bit sleep and more digging I found this helped me:

```
journalctl -b0 _PID=1 | grep Failed
```

PID=1 is the systemd process, which apparently is the one handling the whole boot process.

I have gotten of "cheap".

Fail2ban, opendkim, atd.service and smartd.service had stopped working.

Now I just have to figure out why. :-)